# how to configure Varnish, Nginx Virtual Host & Letsencrypt SSL together

Tags: server, nginx, ssl, letsencrypt, varnish

I need some help in configuration of Varnish Cache, Nginx, & SSL on virtual hosts. I am able to configure the Varnish & Nginx on the server IP (Default virtual host). When I access site at `http` I am able to see
`curl -I http://example.com`
[image]

But when use same domain with SSL `( curl -I https://example.xom )` I get this

[image]

Can someone guide me what are the steps to configure SSL on Varnish Cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Nginx to handle TLS traffic, you might as well configure a TLS virtual host in Nginx that proxies traffic to Varnish.

Here's an example configuration in Nginx:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }

}
```

You can merge it with your existing TLS config for Nginx. Just ensure that you're proxying the content to Varnish via `proxy_pass` instead of just serving content locally.

In this case you'll use Nginx as a TLS proxy, not as a web server.